# ¿como limpiar request.POST? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo un proceso de pago con tarjeta. Al realizar la confirmación de la transacción quiero poder eliminar los datos de POST para que no pueda realizar una nueva transacción al recargar la página.

Mi código es este:

```
def comprar(request,producto,stock):
if request.POST:
    producto = get_object_or_404(Producto, slug = producto)
    foto = Foto.objects.filter(producto = producto)
    perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario = request.user)
    comision = Comision.objects.get(id = 1)
    stock = Stock.objects.get(producto = producto, id = stock)
    promocion = Promocion.objects.get(id = 1)
    form = PayerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if promocion.activo:
            promo = promocion
            gastos_envio = promocion.precio_oferta
            total = producto.p_venta + gastos_envio
        else:
            gastos_envio = comision.gastos_envio
            total = producto.p_venta + gastos_envio
        tarjeta_data = form.clean()
        if tarjeta_data['guardar']:
            guardar_tarjeta(tarjeta_data, perfil)
        comision = Comision.objects.get()
        if producto.perfil.boutique:
            p_comision = comision.comision_boutique
        else:
            p_comision = comision.comision
        cal_comision = round(((p_comision * producto.p_venta) / 100),2)
        cal_iva = round(((comision.impuesto * cal_comision) / 100),2)
        pedido = Pedido(p_prod = producto.p_venta,
                        p_envio = gastos_envio,
                        cp_nom_producto = producto.nombre,
                        cp_estado = producto.estado_prod,
                        cp_talla = stock.talla.valor,
                        cp_marca = producto.marca.nombre,
                        cp_nombre_completo = producto.perfil.usuario.first_name + producto.perfil.usuario.last_name,
                        cp_direccion = perfil.entrg_direccion,
                        cp_ciudad = perfil.entrg_ciudad.name,
                        cp_dep = perfil.entrg_dep.name,
                        cp_pais = perfil.entrg_pais.name,
                        cp_telefono = perfil.tel,
                        perfil = perfil,
                        producto = producto,
                        cp_email = perfil.usuario.email,
                        cp_comision = cal_comision,
                        cp_impuesto = cal_iva,
                        cp_total = total,
                        nit_o_cedula = producto.perfil.cedula_o_nit)
        pedido.estado_pago = 3
        pedido.save()
        resultado = realizar_compra(pedido,perfil,tarjeta_data,request)
        return confirmacion_pago(request,perfil,pedido,resultado)
    return redirect('proceso-compra',slug=producto.slug)
```

y esta es la función a la que lo mando en caso de que el proceso se haya completado correctamente:

```
def confirmacion_pago(request,perfil,pedido,resultado):
perfil = Perfil.objects.get(usuario = request.user)
producto = pedido.producto
foto = Foto.objects.filter(producto = producto)
comision = Comision.objects.get(id = 1)
if pedido.estado_pago == 3:
    if resultado['code'] == 'SUCCESS':
        pedido.id_transaccion = resultado['transactionId']
        pedido.estado_pago = 2
        tallas = Stock.objects.filter(producto = producto)
        stock = tallas.get(talla__valor = pedido.cp_talla)
        stock.cantidad = stock.cantidad - 1
        stock.save()
        is_vendido = True
        for t in tallas:
            if t.cantidad != 0:
                is_vendido = False
        if is_vendido == True:
            producto.estado_rev = 5
            producto.save()
        if perfil.boutique == False:
            transferencia = comision.gastos_transferencia
        else:
            transferencia = comision.gastos_transferencia_boutique
        if producto.perfil.boutique == False:
            transferencia = comision.gastos_transferencia
        else:
            transferencia = comision.gastos_transferencia_boutique
        cal_comision = round(((p_comision * producto.p_venta) / 100),2)
        cal_iva = round(((comision.impuesto * cal_comision) / 100),2)
        total = round(producto.p_venta - cal_comision - cal_iva,2)
        Transaccion.objects.create(pedido=pedido, 
                                    perfil=pedido.producto.perfil,
                                    concepto=1,
                                    cantidad=total + transferencia - pedido.p_envio,
                                    comision=cal_comision,
                                    iva=cal_iva,
                                    gastos_gestion=0,
                                    gasto_transferencia=transferencia)
        html = render_to_string('intranet/emails/compra.html',{'pedido':pedido,'foto':foto[0].path,'domain': 'www.chikka.com.co'})
        msg = EmailMessage('Te han hecho una compra', html, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[producto.perfil.usuario.email])
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.send(fail_silently=False)
        conexion = SoapConexion()
        nombre_contacto = pedido.perfil.usuario.first_name + ' ' + pedido.perfil.usuario.last_name
        nombre_remitente = pedido.producto.perfil.usuario.first_name + ' ' + pedido.producto.perfil.usuario.last_name
        pedido.save()
        request.POST = {}
    return render(request, 'intranet/confirmacion_comprar.html',{'resultado':resultado,'perfil':perfil,'producto':producto,'foto':foto[0],
            'gastos_envio':comision.gastos_envio,'total':pedido.cp_total,'form':PayerForm(),'pedido':pedido})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que eso no suceda, verifica que en el `return render(...` no estes enviando datos sensibles

Comment: yo no devuelvo los datos ya que vuelvo a enviar el formulario vacío y limpio el request.POST pero se queda guardado en el navegador.

Comment: Cuando dices que queda guardado en el navegador a qué te refieres? es decir, que parte del navegador conserva los datos?

Comment: Actualizo la información en la pregunta

Comment: Ok, pero eso no lo puedes eliminar, esa es la petición que le hiciste al servidor. No es que esté guardada, simplemente es una muestra de qué le entregaste al servidor para que te devolviera la página actual en el estado actual. No debes preocuparte por los datos que están ahí, si tienes el servidor bien configurado y con SSL, seguramente nadie tendrá acceso a eso, nadie más que el usuario que proporciona esa información

Comment: pero al hacer la recarga vuelve a generar la misma petición con los mismos datos. Creo que voy a tener que hacerle un redirect a otra url para que no pueda recargar

Comment: Claro, piensa que cada vez que cargas una página en el navegador es gracias a una petición, en este caso la petición tiene unos datos en el post, si recargas esa página, nuevamente tiene que enviar esa petición al servidor, y si el servidor no verifica, vuelve a procesarla de la misma forma. Quizás lo mejor sea redireccionar a otra página, pero sucedería lo mismo en el caso que quieras devolverte, por lo que te recomiendo tener un poco mas de control sobre esto del lado del servidor, y verificar así sea por timestamp

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75969/discussion-between-f-delgado-and-german-alzate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bajo mi punto de vista deberias asignar un nuevo form antes de hacer el **return render**
algo asi:

```
formPayer = PayerForm() #nueva instancia del form 
return render(request, 'intranet/confirmacion_comprar.html',{'resultado':resultado,'perfil':perfil,'producto':producto,'foto':foto[0],
            'gastos_envio':comision.gastos_envio,'total':pedido.cp_total,'form':formPayer,'pedido':pedido})
```

Comment: si ves al final del código, ya lo hago, solo que no lo meto en una variable. Funciona de la misma manera, pero eso no limpia el POST. Creo que la solucion más factible será hacerle una redirección a otra URL distinta